# How to get sorted counters from Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, hector

I have a row of counters and I want to get its' columns sorted by values. Is there any strategies or data models for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no way of having Cassandra do this for you; you will need to get the entire row from Cassandra (paging for large rows) and sort it in the client.

You could use a periodic MapReduce job to do this for you, and cache the result of the job back into Cassandra, if your solution can cope with non-uptodate results.

Comment: It's much more complicated than it sounds. That's probably the reason it is not implemented yet.